# CanCan load_and_authorize_resource does not enforce authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan, cancancan

I have multiple customers in the database and each of them can have multiple admins but I want to keep those customers separate and prevent from viewing each others information. I have added the following code to the ability model:

```
if admin_user.has_role? :admin
  can [:read, :show, :edit, :update, :new_tester, :create_tester, :delete_tester], Customer, id: admin_user.customer_id
end
```

When checking in the console, the abilities are set correctly.
Unfortunately even though I have added load_and_authorize_resource in the controller, admin users are able to view pages (such as edit) for other customers. This is not an expected behaviour- could you please tell me if this is a bug?

This is how my controller looks like:

```
class Admin::CustomersController < Admin::AdminController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  skip_authorize_resource :only => :increase_click_counter

  def edit
  ...
  end
 ...
end
```

Comment: The problem might be due the namespaced controller you have.
Could you try `load_and_authorize_resource :customer`

Comment: I tried that but it unfortunately had no effect.

Comment: Is there no other code in your ability model? I suspect some other line causes that authorize call to return true.